# what logic to use on my control panel CMS in PHP

Tags: php

i am trying to make a control panel for my site, but i have no idea on what logic to use.
for example my control panel has an **add user button**,what i would like to happen is that when a user clicks on that button.. the page will show up on a specific `<div></div>` with out refreshing the page.

The logic i was thinking was:

1.to use an iframe and load all the relevant pages their(which i don't know the PRO's and CON's)

2.Use FLASH, for the control panel(which i don't know the PRO's and CON's)

3.Use javascript or a JS library like JQuery which i don't know what to call it..

the question is what logic would i use, or you can advise something more secured and netter. thanks

Comment: you need to start something and when you have a specific problem come back here and ask. All your options are do-able , it is up to you to decide what to do , but looking at existing CMS for instance.

Comment: ok mr.camus i'll go with number 3 then. . . thanks to mr. @jonathan Sampson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect people to frequently add users from this page, it might be wise to just load the form necessary for adding users into the DOM to begin with, and toggle its visibility when the admin clicks on this button.

The last option you mentioned, loading data asynchronously with jQuery (or any JS library), would also be pretty trivial. There are numerous ways you could do that, but one simple method is to just use the Ajax [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method:

```
$(".addUser").on("click", function(){
  $("#myDiv").load("/addUserForm.php");
});
```

Comment: thanks sir, is this what they do strictly in the industry, i'm looking forward to make a site which has industry standards in it..

Comment: @tomexsans *Industry Standards*? There's no rule-book. You do what works, within reason. Some people will load the DOM up with this form, while others will opt for loading it in much later, upon request. Evaluate your needs and those of your users and act accordingly.